# AngularJS ng-repeat and $index provides parsing error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following code, will produce the right output, but will crash the angularjs code.

```
<tr ng-repeat="elnr in elnrs | orderBy: elnr">
    <td>
        <center>{{elnr.elnr}}</center><button ng-click="elnrs.rmElNr({{$index}})" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Remove {{$index}}</button>          
    </td>
</tr>
```

The fault is in the following code:

```
ng-click="elnrs.rmElNr({{$index}})"
```

Where i want, to pass on the index, to an function in my controller, if i hard code the $index with 0 as an example it works fine. The error is as follows:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '$index' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 16 of the expression [elnrs.rmElNr({{$index}})] starting at [$index}})].
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to put the {{ }} around the $index in ng-click.  Pass it into the ng-click directly and it will recognize it as the index value for the ng-repeat.